# edit css to move user icon and cart

Tags: mobile, mediaquery

I can't move the user and cart icons to the right. Can you help me? I'll share the site inspection images to make things easier.

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWgAh.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWgAh.jpg)[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVskn.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVskn.jpg)]